# C# Winforms - Cannot Access Disposed Object

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, exception

C# .net 3.5 Winforms application.

So here is the situation. I have a form that runs some code to that opens another forms in another thread. When that form opens, it performs certain tasks and then needs to close if those conditions are met. Problem is, it keeps throwing this exception and I have NO idea why.

[image: Exception Text]([![http://i.imgur.com/WFymZdR.jpg]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEa11.png))

Here are my snippets of code used in all this.:

Here is the function that opens the form in another thread: Program.cs

```
    public static void new_downloader_thread()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(open_downloader));
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

        if (Open_Downloader)
        {
            t.Start();
        }
    }
    public static void open_downloader()
    {
        try
        {
            Application.Run(new DownloadInstall());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(e));
        }
    }
```

Here is the code from the form that opens the form giving me the trouble: Manager.cs

```
    private void new_System_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Program.Open_Downloader == false)
        {
            Program.Current_Download = "newsys.exe";
            Program.Open_Downloader = true;
            Program.new_downloader_thread();
        }
        else
        {
            download_busy();
        }
    }
```

Here is the form that is opening: DownloadInstall.cs

```
public partial class DownloadInstall : Form
{
    /// Opening Declarations
    private static System.Net.WebClient web_client;
    private static System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stop_watch;

    private static bool downloading { get; set; }
    private static bool is_name_update { get; set; }

    private static int download_state { get; set; }
    private static int elapsed { get; set; }
    private static int opening { get; set; }
    //private static int counter;
    /// --------------------

    public DownloadInstall()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        is_name_update = false;
        downloading = false;
        opening = 0;

        web_client = new System.Net.WebClient();
        web_client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(Download_Progress);
        web_client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Download_Complete);
        stop_watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

        /// Keypress event call and blanking out the box text.
        this.name_update_field.Text = "";
        this.name_update_field.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(no_period);
        /// --------------------------------------------------

        /// Changes the text to what file we are downloading.
        this.file_name.Text = string.Format("Downloading {0}", Program.Current_Download);
        /// -------------------------------------------------

        /// Sets a forms closed event handler
        this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(Download_Window_Closing);
        /// ---------------------------------

        /// Creates folder where files are to be downloaded and deletes any residual files.
        try
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Downloads");
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(string.Format(@"C:\Downloads\{0}", Program.Current_Download)))
        {
            try
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(string.Format(@"C:\Downloads\{0}", Program.Current_Download));
            }
            catch
            {
                if (Program.Disconnecting == false)
                {
                    opening = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        /// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        switch (opening)
        {
            /// Case 0 Starts the download or name update code normally.
            case 0:
                if (Program.Current_Download == "Name Update")
                {
                    file_name.Text = "Name Update Downloader";
                    is_name_update = true;
                    this.restart_or_start.Text = "Start";
                    this.cid.Visible = true;
                    this.name_update_field.ReadOnly = false;
                    this.name_update_field.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Download_Begin();
                }
                break;

            /// Case 1 will close the downloader.
            case 1:
                MessageBox.Show("It is possible this file was already downloaded and is already open on this computer.", "Hmmmmm...", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                this.Close();
                break;
        }

    }


    /// Function that is called when the window is closed.
    private void Download_Window_Closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (downloading)
        {
            web_client.CancelAsync();
        }
        Program.Current_Download = "";
        Program.Open_Downloader = false;
    }
    /// --------------------------------------------------
```

Not sure why this is throwing the exception. It seems if I remove code that closes the form, it works, and I can close the form properly from other parts of the code. Any help would be great!

Comment: Where is the code for `Download_Window_Closing`?

Comment: @DangerZone I just edited my post to include that.

Comment: @DangerZone I solved it. I changed `this.Close();`  `to Load += (s, e) => Close();` It seems my problem is I am trying to close the form before the constructor finished fully executing so the object had no reference.

Comment: Why do people down vote...really now! This could actually help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!! The problem is when trying to close the form before it has finished construction.

Changed:

```
this.Close();
```

to:

```
Load += (s, e) => Close();
```